# Remove and add widget from QStatusBar

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qstatusbar

I have an application with a status bar to which I would like to add/remove a permanent widget (because I need it on the right).
My idea is simple: I have a QLabel widget initially hidden and it will be visible only when a user checks the checkbox.

The first time the users check the box, the widget is created perfectly, then hiding it back is as simple as `QStatusBar::removeWidget(QWidget *widget)`, however, I am unable to add my widget back to my status bar since I have no clue how to implement the show() function. I read the documentation but is unclear to me:

> void QStatusBar::removeWidget(QWidget *widget)
> Removes the specified widget from the status bar.
>
> Note: This function does not delete the widget but hides it. To add
> the widget again, you must call both the addWidget() and show()
> functions.

Here is a small extract of my code:

```
def statusbarCheckbox(self, s):
    if s.isChecked():    
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.label_widget)
        # what am I  missing here? 
        # show() !?
    else :
        self.statusbar.removeWidget(self.label_widget)
```

I'm sure I'm missing some basic line on my if statement, which is when the widget should be shown again, but I am not sure what to add in there.

Comment: `self.label_widget.show()`.

Comment: Wow easier than expected! thank you @ekhumoro